# QGIS plugin giving path error at startup

Tags: qgis, windows

Somehow I've managed to get this to popup every time I start QGIS:
`The extra plugin path '%AppData%\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins' does not exist!`

[image]

Any ideas where to look to get rid of it? (The path `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins`exists and I have my plugins in the folder..)

Comment: have you tried creating that directory?

Comment: I assume that %AppData% is "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming" (and in that I case I already have it)